# Display related custom taxonomy posts in sidebar

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

Can I use this snippet to retrieve posts from a custom taxonomy in a custom post type?

```
<?php $sermon_series = new WP_Query( array('series' => 'type')); ?>

<?php while ($sermon_series->have_posts()) : $sermon_series->the_post(); ?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It displays regular posts now, but I need it to display posts from a custom post type called "Sermons" in my wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reference:** [`WordPress Codex — Custom Taxonomies > Querying by taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Querying_by_taxonomy)

Creating a taxonomy generally automatically creates a special query variable using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class, which we can use to retrieve posts based on. For example, to pull a list of posts that have "Bob" as a "person" taxonomy in them, we will use:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'person' => 'bob' ) );
```

or, for more complex argument:

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'person',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'bob'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What's above is quoted from [the document](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Querying_by_taxonomy) I linked far above, and I think it's very very relevant/close to what you are doing.

**Solution:**

```
<?php query_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'sermon', 'sermon_series' => $sermon_series )); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></small>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up finally figuring it out.

Comment: @ftntravis I took the liberty to edit your question, take the answer and add it in mine. (Answers are not supposed to be in questions.) If you want I can edit my answer and remove it, so that you can add your own answer. :)